# Google OAuth2 - how to set access type?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

Am trying to use **OAuth 2.0** to avoid adding YAP (yet another password) to the world. The PHP implementation of google OAuth seems to work quite well with the (albeit small) issue of setting the type of access being requested.

App is setup to use the 'identity toolkit API' only. In the sign in I'm not calling the `setAccessType` but the 'offline mode' seems to be the default permission requested. Truthfully, I want the user id and not much else.

While I was experimenting with the PHP samples quite often it would tell me it needed email address and some other personal bits but I haven't been able to figure out how to set this.

It's a small matter but seems like a reasonable thing to notify users about.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the `scope` parameter. For Google logins scopes are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes). Likely `profile` is the one you are looking for.

> I don't know which library you are using, but all it takes is a `scope` query string param on the authorization request.